# jQuery/JS: Album-viewer "next/prev"

Tags: jquery

Continue from this:

[Making album-viewer like facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706745/making-album-viewer-like-facebook/4706871),
where i got to know the server side behind making a album-viewer´s next/prev,

Now I would like to know what I should do to change the adressbar url at the top from ?view=1 to ?view=2? So the adressbar follows/updates, as the new image gets appended and showed(on success)..

Facebook have done it, so as you browse through a album it changes the url to the current image´s link..

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of history and have better boomarking with ajax functionality in javascript by linking to and listening for changes in the hash (#) part of the url.

There are a bunch of good jQuery plugins for this, for example:

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/